# pdflatex path problem

Tags: pdftex, paths, macports

I am having a problem running pdflatex on the command line. When I install a new package using `tlmgr` it puts things in the the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/` which is fine. When I compile my .tex files from a program like TexShop everything works fine, but when I try to run `pdflatex` from the commandline I run into issues. It can't find the appropriate .cls and other things. I went looking into the .log files to see what was going on. When I compline from TexShop the start of the .log file says

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) 
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.5.25)
```

but when I use `pdflatex` on the command line I get

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/MacPorts 2014_1)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.10.13)
```

I was messing around with Macports a few months back and might have installed some stuff for Latex but I don't remember. I updated all of my MacPort stuff thinking that something was out of date but that didn't change anything. It appears that the `TeX Live 2014/MacPorts 2014_1` is looking for files in `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/` which doesn't have the new packages I installed using `tlmgr`. I would like `pdflatex` to look for files in `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/` where all of my packages are. I also don't know what is going on with the Tex Live and the Tex Live / MacPorts but if I can get `pdflatex` to work then it doesn't really matter. Thanks for your time, and I am sorry if I haven't provided enough information.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the MacPorts TeX Live, that's all. I removed MacPorts from all my machines time ago, to be honest.

Comment: @egreg Do you use a package manager for your mac machines?

Comment: I use homebrew and I feel no nostalgia for MacPorts or Fink. Can you show the output of `echo $PATH` from a terminal window?

Comment: `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin`

Comment: Add `export PATH=/usr/texbin:${PATH}` at the end of your `.bashrc` file and MacTeX binaries will be used.